# Notifications not appearing until a day later

Tags: notifications, calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-20

Events that I put into the (Google?) Calendar app that came preinstalled usually don't show a notification until at least 24 hours later. For instance, it's now just after 7:00 pm, 30 June 2023 Melbourne time, yet I was just notified of an event at 6:00 pm, 29 June 2023, just over 25 hours ago.

My phone is a Samsung S20 Ultra, with all the updates available on my network carrier.

What could be causing this and how could I fix it?